# What can I do better to clean this code up, make it smaller? Just started practicing clean code, need advice

Tags: c#

I feel like this code could be cleaned up more or it could be shorter but and more understandable. Any advice/suggestion is appreciated.

```
public string GetIPVersions(NetworkInterface @interface)
    {
        string ipVersions = "";

        if (@interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4)) ipVersions += NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4;

        if (!@interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6)) return ipVersions;

        ipVersions += ipVersions.Length > 0 ? $" {NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6}" : $"{NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6}";

        return ipVersions;
    }

 private void UpdatePageText()
    {
        int interfacesCount = Interfaces.Count();
        InterfaceCountText = interfacesCount > 0 ? $"{interfacesCount} interfaces found" : "No interfaces found";
    }
```

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, applies to too many questions on this site to be useful. The site standard is for the title to **simply state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Here's something I never thought I'd say: look up FizzBuzz and what solutions people find to it - it will be helpful for you to decide how to approach this.

Answer (score 2):

Switching the logic `@interface.Supports` vs `!@interfaceSupports` is confusing the code.

The decision to add a space is better as a distinct statement.  Blending this decision with the addition of the IPv6 text obscures the meaning of the code.

With just two cases, you can be more direct:

```
public string GetIPVersions(NetworkInterface @interface) {
    boolean supportsIPv4 = ( @interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4) );
    boolean supportsIPv6 = ( @interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6) ); 

    if ( supportsIPv4 ) {
        if ( supportsIPv6 ) {
            return NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4 + " " + NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6;
        } else {
            return NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4;
        }
    } else if ( supportsIPv6 ) {
        return NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Keeping the code closer to you original method:

```
public string GetIPVersions(NetworkInterface @interface) {
    string ipVersions = "";

    if ( @interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4) ) {
        ipVersions += NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4;
    }

    if ( @interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6) ) {
        if ( ipVersions.Length > 0 ) {
            ipVersions += " ";
        }
        ipVersions += NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6;
    }

    return ipVersions;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting to see how this essentially boils down to FizzBuzz.

Answer (score 0):

The Code looks neat and clean. If you want you can change this to

```
private void UpdatePageText()
    {
        InterfaceCountText = Interfaces.Count() > 0 ? $"{Interfaces.Count()} interfaces found" : "No interfaces found";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach although it may be a tad less understandable.
Essentially it creates an array of strings or null, filters out the nulls, and joins the remaining with a separator.
One advantage of this approach is that it can be easily extended to support more cases.

```
public string GetIPVersions(NetworkInterface @interface)
{
    return
        String.Join(
            " ",
            new string[] {
                @interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4) ? NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4.ToString() : null,
                @interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6) ? NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6.ToString() : null,
            }
            .Where(x => x != null));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first function has some convoluted logic: the if and if(!) that does an unexpected return in the middle, the extra ternary to handle the space. That's a lot to follow for what boils down to showing IPV4 and/or IPV6.

For simple functions it's not a big deal, but I would try to keep the different pieces distinct, dead-simple, and top-down. `string.Join()` is perfect for space or comma-separated concatenation, let's use it.

```
    public string GetIpVersions(NetworkInterface @interface) {
        var supported = new List<NetworkInterfaceComponent>();

        if (@interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4)) supported.Add(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4);
        if (@interface.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6)) supported.Add(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv6);

        return string.Join(" ", supported);
    }
```

`UpdatePageText()` is fine to me.